# How to prevent click on outside of polygons in Leaflet map js?

Tags: jquery, leaflet, openstreetmap

We have multiple arrays of lat long, ( here 3 arrays are stored in **success_content_mapareas** )
Accordingly, we have created the map and it looks like this, which seems okay in the image below.
[image]

We need to prevent click out side the polygon.

```
var success_content_mapareas = res.area_labels;

if (success_content_mapareas != "") {
  var map = L.map("map").setView([26.250930597138844, 43.98925781250001], 5);

  L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  }).addTo(map);

  jQuery.each(success_content_mapareas, function (index, success_content_mapareas) {
    L.polygon(success_content_mapareas).addTo(map);
  });

  function onMapClick(e) {
    var latlong_test = e.latlng;
    console.log(latlong_test);
    jQuery.get(
      "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverseformat=jsonv2&lat=" + latlong_test.lat + "&lon=" + latlong_test.lng,
      function (data) {
        console.log(data.display_name);
        jQuery("#bs_quick_shipping_full_address").val(data.display_name);
      },
    );
  }

  map.on("click", onMapClick);
}
```

We have used this,

```
https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js
```

```
https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css
```

We need to prevent clicking outside the polygon, or alert message, or something like that.
Currently, we are getting lat - long of clicked areas in the map
you can see in the console.

Ref. https://leafletjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding click event to map by doing `map.on("click", onMapClick);` you could set click event to each of your polygons as,

```
...
jQuery.each(success_content_mapareas, function (index, success_content_mapareas) {
    var poly = L.polygon(success_content_mapareas).addTo(map);
    // add click event to polygon
    poly.on("click", function (e) {
        doPolyClick(e);
    });
});

function doPolyClick(ev) {
    console.log(ev.latlng);
} 
...
```